# Prove that if $f$ is an element of Lip $\alpha$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

I am required to prove that if $f$ is an element of Lip $\alpha$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous. Where Lip means a Lipschitz function. I also have to  prove that if $f$ is an element of Lip $\alpha$ and $\alpha>1$ then $f$ is constant where $\alpha$ is actually a greek symbol I dont know how to type

i) Prove that if $f \in$ Lip $\alpha$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

ii) Prove that if $f \in $ Lip $\alpha$ and $\alpha > 1 $, then $f$ is constant.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the definitions of Lipschitz and uniformly continuity?

Comment: Yes we have that  a function: [a,b]->R satisfies a Lipschitz condition of order a > 0 if there is some positive constant M so that abs(f(x1)-f(x2)) <= M*abs(x1-x2)^a and Lip a denoted the set of all functions satisfying a Lipschitz condition of order a

Comment: Yes. Hence for all $x_1$, given $\epsilon > 0$ you can choose an $\delta$ such that ... the appropriate implication holds. As we can do that for all $x_1$ in the domain of $f$, Lipschitz implies uniform continuity.

Comment: Okay  so I think I did the first part and now how would I do this for >1 ?

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, if $f \in Lip(\alpha > 1)$, then

$$| f(x) - f(y)| \leq | x - y|^\alpha \ \ \Longrightarrow  \ \ \frac{| f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|} \leq |x - y|^{\alpha - 1}$$

where $\alpha - 1 > 0$

Now what can you deduce from that?

Comment: it goes to 0 therefore the reason why f is constant?

Comment: *Last hint:* The ratio on the right looks like the definition of derivative. Hmmm

Comment: So this says that the derivative exists but is 0 everywhere in R

Comment: If the derivative of $f$ is everywhere zero, $f'(x) = 0$, then $f(x) = c$ a constant.